# How to write to a textfile in c (with the intended functionality)

Tags: c, text, text-files

I am trying to learn the syntax for writing data(chars, integers and strings). I have studied the contents of the following link http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_files.html and written the following code. The aim of the code is to store the data in the text file in the following manner:

33
Hello

15
Ok

if I make the following inputs 33, Hello, 15, Ok and 0. But the text file is completely blank when I open it after running the program. 
Is there anyone here that is skilled in storing data in a text document that can give me some hints in what I am doing wrong?  Or if there is any other good tutorials that you know?

My test code is attached below[I can compile and run it without any problem except that it doesn't do the things that I expect:( ]

```
char stdin_buff[20];
int stdin_int;
FILE *fp;
char *filename = "data.txt"; //name of the textfile where the data should be stored 

void handle_String_input(char msg[]){
    fp = fopen(filename, "w"); //opens the text file in write mode
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Unable to open the file! \n");
    }
    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END); //seek the end of the text file
    fputs(msg,fp); //writes the message to the text file
    putc('\n',fp); //new line in the text document
    putc('\n',fp); //new line in the text document 
    fclose(fp); //closes the text file
}

void handle_Integer_input(int nbr){
    fp = fopen(filename, "w"); //opens the text file in write mode
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Unable to open the file! \n");
    }
    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END); //seek the end of the text file
    fputc(nbr,fp); //writes the nbr into the text file 
    putc('\n',fp); //new line in the text document 
    fclose(fp); //closes the text file
}

void main(){
    while(1){
        memset(stdin_buff,'\0',10); //clears the content of stdin_buff 
        printf("Enter an integer(enter 0 to exit): ");
        fgets(stdin_buff,9,stdin); //retrieves an input from keyboard(the user is expected to only use the numbers 0-9)
        stdin_int=atoi(stdin_buff);
        handle_Integer_input(stdin_int);
        if(stdin_int==0){
            break;
        }
        memset(stdin_buff,'\0',10); //clears the content of stdin_buff 
        printf("Enter a string(enter 0 to exit): ");
        fgets(stdin_buff,9,stdin); //retrieves input from keyboard
        handle_String_input(stdin_buff);
        if(stdin_buff[0]=='0'){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What have I missed/ not understood? Any suggestions on improvements are appreciated!

Comment: You might be interested by textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/) and the libraries implementing them like [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) and many others. You should also investigate [lexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexing) and [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036201/writing-to-an-output-file-in-c-mpi/23036288

Comment: @Jongware: I don't see an immediate relation between this question and MPI...

Comment: "You are repeatedly opening your output file a-new for writing. By default, that will truncate it to 0 bytes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fopen statement, use "a" (for append) instead of "w". "w" [clears the file](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).

Currently, if you end your interactive session by entering an integer '0', then the file will appear empty. If you end with a string '0' you should see just the character 0.

Comment: Also, writing the integer `1` into this file will not make it contain a *line* "1\n".